# Highcharts - Data label cut off

Tags: highcharts

I took a sample jsfiddle and modified it here just to show a sample of what I experienced:
http://jsfiddle.net/pMwuv/

Here is what my actual datalabel code looks like:

```
dataLabels: {
enabled: true,
align: 'left',
verticalAlign: 'top',
style: {
    color: 'black'
},
formatter: function () {
    if (this.x == 19) {
        return this.y + '<br>units left';
    };
}
}
```

What I am having on my area chart is that the last data label is cut off. Is there a way to increase the width of the container or add some type of padding so that the full label shows?

Just changing the x and y position of the label will not work for my area chart. I have my chart customized so that only the last point of the chart has a data label and i want it aligned to the right of the last point and not within the chart.

But if we can get the above sample fiddle to work then the same solution should work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add [marginRight](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.marginRight) to `chart` like this:

```
chart: {
           renderTo: container,
           width: 550,
           marginRight: 35 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexpert/D8r9a/).

Comment: Both marginRight and spacingRight seem to work! Is there a situation where it would be better to use one or another?

Comment: Yes, there are situations when `spacingRight` is better. For example, when you have legends on the right. `spacingRight` is a space between the right edge of the chart and the whole _content_ (including legends). `marginRight` is the margin between the right outer edge of the chart and the _plot area_.  So if you apply marginRight for chart with legend on the right, you will have a space between legend and the plot area. But in your case it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a *direct* solution, but I suggest you to put the label at the yAxis:

```
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Units left'
        }
    },
```

And remove the other attributes, leaving just `enabled: true`:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMwuv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set [spacingRight](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.spacingRight) and add correct value.